# New to Hiredis (or Redis)

Tags: redis, hiredis

Sorry in advance as I am new to this community and can be unknowledgeable. This is my first time using redis/hiredis for my c project. In fact, my first time using a key value database and I am just too used to the normal SQL database with tables and interface. I tried downloading the hiredis/redis and open the file to have a look. It was filled with c and h files and I was quite lost.

I tried following some instructions where they told me to key in some commands but I have no idea where to do that. I'm sorry but is it possible that anyone here can guide me through? I'm sorry once again because I'm really new to this in general and the information I looked up online isn't going through my brain well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that you downloaded the redis source code and get lost in there. Just to use redis, you don't need it's source to integrate with your app. Its a standalone server. Download redis binary->install it ->run the server-> use redis-cli to query -> then language specific driver to connect from your app. Thats all.

Comment: https://redis.io/download check this links and instruction there. After installing and starting the server: 
https://redis.io/topics/rediscli

Comment: Redis binary as in the win64 file right? I manage to download it and run the service in my computer, However, whenever I try to open the redis-server.exe, it opens for a split second and closes. Do you have any idea why is this so? I look up then internet and they said something about running it through the cmd but I tried and it didn't work